# Forcing figures position in (last page) column

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column

I'm writing a two columns document and I have two figures on the last page stacked in one column. The first one at the top and the second one almost at the bottom. How can I force the second one to be shown just after the first one with no empty lines between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the two graphics/diagrams and their captions within a single `figure` environment (with some vertical space added between graphic 1 and graphic 2).

EDIT: Cross-referencing works as usual -- put `\label` commands after each `\caption`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:a}
\bigskip
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Another figure}\label{fig:b}
\end{figure}

See figure~\ref{fig:a} and figure~\ref{fig:b}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I reference the two figures and still having them listed with two different major numbers (like Fig. 1 and Fig. 2)?

Comment: @andrea: See updated answer.

Comment: @andrea: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote my answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and possibly to accept it (by clicking on the checkmark; you can do so with a reputation of 1).